# Unable to submit list of LocalTime in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this entity that contains a list of objects (omitted getters and setters and all irrelevant code for this example)

```
public class SampleType {
    @OneToMany
    List<SampleTypeTime> sampleTypeTimes = new ArrayList<SampleTypeTime>();
}

public class SampleTypeTime {
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.TIME)
    LocalTime time;
}
```

And i have this form that allows the user to select multiple hours..

```
<form th:object="${sampleType}" th:method="POST" th:action="@{#}">
    <select th:field="*{sampleTypeTimes}" type="time" class="form-control" multiple>
        <option th:value="00:00" th:text="${"00:00"}"></option>
        <option th:value="01:00" th:text="${"01:00"}"></option>
        ... and so on
    </select>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
@PostMapping("sampletype/")
public String productsTypesPost(@ModelAttribute SampleType sampleType, Model model) {
    sampleTypeRepository.save(sampleType);
    return "sampletype";
}
```

When i submit the form i get the following error message:

```
Field error in object 'sampleType' on field 'sampleTypeTimes': rejected value [00:00,02:00];
codes [typeMismatch.sampleType.sampleTypeTimes,typeMismatch.sampleTypeTimes,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch];
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [sampleType.sampleTypeTimes,sampleTypeTimes];
arguments []; default message [sampleTypeTimes]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'sampleTypeTimes';
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.project.SampleTypeTime' for property 'sampleTypeTimes[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

It seems to me that it struggles converting String[] to  List, how can i get around this?

Edit: added controller class

Comment: Your form returns value of type `String` for property `sampleTypeTimes`. While the property of the class is of type `List`. No wander you get exception. Could you apply the method of controller which processes the form?

Comment: Added the controller class to the question

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, form returns value of `String` while the array contains instances of `SampleTypeTime`. You need to tell Spring how to convert `String` to `SampleTypeTime`. For doing that you have to create implementation of `PropertyEditor`:

```
public class SampleTypeTimeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(text);
        SampleTypeTime sampleTime = new SampleTypeTime();
        sampleTime.setTime(time);
        setValue(appointment);
    }
}
```

In this example code snippet I don't check the text if it has a right format or not. But in real code you should do it of course. After that add the created property editor to the `DataBinder` of your controller:

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(DataBinder binder)        
        binder.registerCustomEditor(SampleTypeTime.class, new SampleTypeTimeEditor());
    }       

    ... 
}
```

Now Spring automatically will convert `String` to `SampleTypeTime`. You can get more information about `PropertyEditor` from [this chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) of the official documentation. And [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) you can get details about `DataBinder`.